# adding tooltip to a bubble in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, d3.js, tooltip

I have the following d3 code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import tip from 'd3';

export default class BubbleChart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.renderChart = this.renderChart.bind(this);
    this.renderBubbles = this.renderBubbles.bind(this);
    this.renderLegend = this.renderLegend.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.svg = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    this.renderChart();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const {
      width,
      height,
    } = this.props;
    if(width !== 0 && height !== 0) {
      this.renderChart();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      width,
      height,
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <svg width={width} height={height} />
    )
  }

  renderChart() {
    const {
      overflow,
      graph,
      data,
      height,
      width,
      padding,
      showLegend,
      legendPercentage,
    } = this.props;
    // Reset the svg element to a empty state.
    this.svg.innerHTML = '';
    // Allow bubbles overflowing its SVG container in visual aspect if props(overflow) is true.
    if(overflow)
      this.svg.style.overflow = "visible";

    const bubblesWidth = showLegend ? width * (1 - (legendPercentage / 100)) : width;
    const legendWidth = width - bubblesWidth;
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

    const pack = d3.pack()
        .size([bubblesWidth * graph.zoom, bubblesWidth * graph.zoom])
        .padding(padding);

    // Process the data to have a hierarchy structure;
    const root = d3.hierarchy({children: data})
    .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; })
    .each((d) => {
      if(d.data.label) {
        d.label = d.data.label;
        d.id = d.data.label.toLowerCase().replace(/ |\//g, "-");
      }
    });

    // Pass the data to the pack layout to calculate the distribution.
    const nodes = pack(root).leaves();

    // Call to the function that draw the bubbles.
    this.renderBubbles(bubblesWidth, nodes, color);
    // Call to the function that draw the legend.
    if (showLegend) {
      this.renderLegend(legendWidth, height, bubblesWidth, nodes, color);
    }
  }
  

  renderBubbles(width, nodes, color) {
    const {
      graph,
      data,
      bubbleClickFun,
      valueFont,
      labelFont
    } = this.props;
   
    const bubbleChart = d3.select(this.svg).append("g")
      .attr("class", "bubble-chart")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (width * graph.offsetX) + "," + (width * graph.offsetY) + ")"; });;

    const node = bubbleChart.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) {
        bubbleClickFun(d.label);
    });
    
    

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r - (d.r * .04); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.data.color ? d.data.color : color(nodes.indexOf(d)); })
      .style("z-index", 5)
      .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("r", d.r * 2.04);
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        const r = d.r - (d.r * 0.04);
        d3.select(this).attr("r", r);
      });

    node.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return "clip-" + d.id; })
      .append("use")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id; });

    // node.append("text")
    //   .attr("class", "value-text")
    //   .style("font-size", `${valueFont.size}px`)
    //   .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d.id + ")"; })
    //   .style("font-weight", (d) => {
    //     return valueFont.weight ? valueFont.weight : 600;
    //   })
    //   .style("font-family", valueFont.family)
    //   .style("fill", () => {
    //     return valueFont.color ? valueFont.color : '#000';
    //   })
    //   .style("stroke", () => {
    //     return valueFont.lineColor ? valueFont.lineColor : '#000';
    //   })
    //   .style("stroke-width", () => {
    //     return valueFont.lineWeight ? valueFont.lineWeight : 0;
    //   })
    //   .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

    node.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label-text")
      .style("font-size", `${labelFont.size}px`)
      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d.id + ")"; })
      .style("font-weight", (d) => {
        return labelFont.weight ? labelFont.weight : 600;
      })
      .style("font-family", labelFont.family)
      .style("fill", () => {
        return labelFont.color ? labelFont.color : '#000';
      })
      .style("stroke", () => {
        return labelFont.lineColor ? labelFont.lineColor : '#000';
      })
      .style("stroke-width", () => {
        return labelFont.lineWeight ? labelFont.lineWeight : 0;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      });


    // Center the texts inside the circles.
    d3.selectAll(".label-text").attr("x", function(d) {
      const self = d3.select(this);
      const width = self.node().getBBox().width;
      return -(width/2);
    })
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
      const self = d3.select(this);
      const width = self.node().getBBox().width;
      d.hideLabel = width*1.05 > (d.r*2);
      return d.hideLabel ? 0 : 1;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return labelFont.size/2
    })

    // Center the texts inside the circles.
    d3.selectAll(".label-text").attr("x", function(d) {
      const self = d3.select(this);
      const width = self.node().getBBox().width;
      return -(width/2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      if (!d.hideLabel) {
        return valueFont.size / 3;
      } else {
        return -valueFont.size * 0.5;
      }
    });

    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
  }
  
  renderLegend(width, height, offset, nodes, color) {
    const {
      data,
      legendClickFun,
      legendFont,
    } = this.props;
    const bubble = d3.select('.bubble-chart');
    const bubbleHeight = bubble.node().getBBox().height;

    const legend = d3.select(this.svg).append("g")
      .attr("transform", function() { return `translate(${offset},${(bubbleHeight)* 0.05})`; })
      .attr("class", "legend");

    let textOffset = 0;
    const texts = legend.selectAll(".legend-text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
        const offset = textOffset;
        textOffset+= legendFont.size + 10;
        return `translate(0,${offset})`;
      })
      .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d3.select('#' + d.id).attr("r", d.r * 1.04);
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        const r = d.r - (d.r * 0.04);
        d3.select('#' + d.id).attr("r", r);
      })
      .on("click", function(d) {
        legendClickFun(d.label);
    });;

    texts.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 30)
      .attr("height", legendFont.size)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", -legendFont.size)
      .style("fill", "transparent");

    texts.append("rect")
      .attr("width", legendFont.size)
      .attr("height", legendFont.size)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", -legendFont.size)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.data.color ? d.data.color : color(nodes.indexOf(d)); });
      
      
    texts.append("text")
      .style("font-size", `${legendFont.size}px`)
      .style("font-weight", (d) => {
        return legendFont.weight ? legendFont.weight : 600;
      })
      .style("font-family", legendFont.family)
      .style("fill", () => {
        return legendFont.color ? legendFont.color : '#000';
      })
      .style("stroke", () => {
        return legendFont.lineColor ? legendFont.lineColor : '#000';
      })
      .style("stroke-width", () => {
        return legendFont.lineWeight ? legendFont.lineWeight : 0;
      })
      .attr("x", (d) => { return legendFont.size + 10 })
      .attr("y", 0)
      .text((d) => { return d.label });
  }
}

BubbleChart.propTypes = {
  overflow: PropTypes.bool,
  graph: PropTypes.shape({
    zoom: PropTypes.number,
    offsetX: PropTypes.number,
    offsetY: PropTypes.number,
  }),
  width: PropTypes.number,
  height: PropTypes.number,
  padding: PropTypes.number,
  showLegend: PropTypes.bool,
  legendPercentage: PropTypes.number,
  legendFont: PropTypes.shape({
    family: PropTypes.string,
    size: PropTypes.number,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    weight: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  valueFont: PropTypes.shape({
    family: PropTypes.string,
    size: PropTypes.number,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    weight: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  labelFont: PropTypes.shape({
    family: PropTypes.string,
    size: PropTypes.number,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    weight: PropTypes.string,
  }),
}
BubbleChart.defaultProps = {
  overflow: false,
  graph: {
    zoom: 1.1,
    offsetX: -0.05,
    offsetY: -0.01,
  },
  width: 1000,
  height: 800,
  padding: 0,
  showLegend: true,
  legendPercentage: 20,
  legendFont: {
    family: 'Arial',
    size: 12,
    color: '#000',
    weight: 'bold',
  },
  valueFont: {
    family: 'Arial',
    size: 16,
    color: '#fff',
    weight: 'bold',
  },
  labelFont: {
    family: 'Arial',
    size: 11,
    color: '#fff',
    weight: 'normal',
  },
  
  bubbleClickFun: (label) => {console.log(`Bubble ${label} is clicked ...`)
  },
  legendClickFun: (label) => {console.log(`Legend ${label} is clicked ...`)}
}
```

when I click on the bubbleClickFun,I want a popover to be displayed with "label-text" attribute.I am using d3 inside a React component.Also a modal or tooltip works too.Any popover or panel kind of thing,that pops up as soon as the bubble is clicked works fine.
Also,I would be able to change the size of popover.This is really important

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre], and make it runnable using a stack snippet. Which version of d3 are you using? d3-tip might not be working with version 6

Comment: d3-tip works actually. d34.13 is the version @RubenHelsloot but the problem is it is not easy to interpret the content with d3-tip

Comment: Make your code runnable and remove the react context. Keep it as simple as possible, that will get you the best answers